# Any way to identify the Computer's OU information from local WMI or Registry

Tags: powershell, active-directory, registry, ou

I'm looking for a way to obtain the OU information of a computer from its local WMI or Registry. I know there are ways to pull the OU information from a host using PowerShell and AD commandlets... Afraid every time we execute the commands, it will hit the domain controller and pull the information. If we run similar commands simultaneously on a large number of computers, it would spike the number of connections to Domain Controllers. We would like to avoid such cases and see if we can find a way to obtain the OU information if it's stored locally in the host.

I did find a few sample codes from other responses and they are working well, however, I feel they are retrieving the information from Domain Controller (sorry if I misunderstood). Could someone confirm if this is the only option we have to use or is there any alternative solution?

Sample Code:

`([adsisearcher]"(&(name=$env:computername)(objectClass=computer))").findall().path`

(or)

`Import-Module ActiveDirectory -Force;`
`Get-ADComputer $env:computername | select -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName`

Thanks,
Nana

Comment: I think the `adsisearcher` alternative you're showing is the most reliable one and will work on any computer having powershell 5.1 it also does not rely on having RSAT installed in the computers (needed to use `Get-AD*` cmdlets). Don't think you should care about too many queries to a DC since each computer will query a DC based on Sites and Services, not all will query the same DC

Comment: I would just change `.findall()` to `.FindOne()` since there can only be only 1 computer with that name in AD

Comment: "it would spike the number of connections" - is this something you've actually observed causing problems, or is it more of an imagined problem? If a single LDAP query for a specific computer account object by name (regardless of whether you use `Get-ADComputer` or `[adsisearcher]`) from each computer in a given site brings your DCs to a halt then you need to re-size :)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for your response. Sure, will use `FindOne()` then. Thanks again!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Just being foresighted... It's not going to bring the DC down, but it will alert the support folks that DC is under attack if let's say 2k to 5k hits simultaneously... We don't have such plans to hit all at once, for now, just in case if we do, we need to answer :)

Comment: To be fair, 5k queries for this particular case is nothing to a DC. Besides it would be pretty hard that all run at that exact moment. A DC can return results for the query you're running in less than a second even for Domains with millions of objects (as long as the DC is a decent one and networking is decent too)